# Send some caracters dont work - String JAVA

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to print some caracters like: '!', '@', '\'
But it's not working at all...
Capital letters don't work too...

I have this string:

```
String admUsr = "HOMP'\'adm03!@";
```

But when i try to print:

```
irf.Send(admUsr);
```

It's printing only:

> hompadm03

Instead of

> HOMP\adm03!@

What is wrong with my send functions?

```
  // mandar textos     
  public void Send(int i)
  {
      try {
        r = new Robot();
        r.delay(40);
        r.keyPress(i);
        r.keyRelease(i);
      } catch (AWTException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(iRobot_Functions.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
  }
  public void Send(String s)
  {
    byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
    for (byte b : bytes)
    {
        try {
            int code = b;
            // keycode only handles [A-Z] (which is ASCII decimal [65-90])
            if (code > 96 && code < 123) code = code - 32;
            r = new Robot();
            r.delay(40);
            r.keyPress(code);
            r.keyRelease(code);
        } catch (AWTException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(iRobot_Functions.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: why did you add this line `if (code > 96 && code < 123) code = code - 32;` Do you know what it does?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I see. In that case, I made it too easy for the OP by answering your question. So I've just deleted my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the incorrect use of KeyPress() method, **DodyCodeExcpetion** has mentioned.
So I'd like to talk about another problem.

The admUsr string.

```
String admUsr = "HOMP'\'adm03!@";
```

the "\'" is an [Escape Sequence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).So the expected output should be

```
HOMP''adm03!@
```

rather than

```
HOMP\adm03!@
```

### Simple Solution

you should process the String in char level instead of in byte level.
you can see the definition of [char & byte here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

And use `KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(int)` method to find out whether there could exist an extended key code for a unicode character. here is the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getExtendedKeyCodeForChar-int-)

```
public void send(String s) {
    if (null == s) return;
    Robot r = null;
    char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
    try {
        for (char c : chars) {
                int code = c;
                int keyCode = KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(code);
                r = new Robot();
                r.delay(40);
                r.keyPress(keyCode);
                r.keyRelease(keyCode);
        } 
    } catch (AWTException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
using \\ fixed the first problem

But about getkeycodeforchar got a problem:
@ have the same code than 2
so as ! have the same code than 1
And i think all others symbos have this problem:
https://barrabase.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/teclado-atalhos-dicas.jpg

So when i try to print:

String admUsr = "HOMP\\adm03!@";
irf.Send(admUsr);

It's printing only:

    homp\adm0312

Instead of

    HOMP\adm03!@

Comment: Hello, Otrz, I just tried to print the key code for  '!', '@' , '1', '2' on my MAC.And I got 517,512,49,50. The print code is like this 
 System.out.println(KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar((int)'1'));

Comment: Hello, Otrz, I have seen the source code of KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(int), then I found out that character '!' is a regular key code which is defined by KeyEvent.VK_EXCLAMATION_MARK. And I don't even know why r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_EXCLAMATION_MARK) can not print the '!' by defined regular key code.This may be a new question.

Comment: Okey, i'll create a new one, thank you so much for this base :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `keyPress()` incorrectly. See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#keyPress-int-). Its argument is not a textual character; it is a keycode. A keycode is one of the fields from the KeyEvent class. It just so happens that "ordinary" ASCII lowercase letters have the same character code as the keycode.

What you need to do is:

1. Read the documentation of the KeyEvent class and find the keycode for the Shift key.
2. To send capital letters, you need to call keyPress/keyRelease for the following events: Shift key pressed; Letter key pressed; Letter key released; Shift key released.
3. To send punctuation marks, look at your keyboard and see which key the punctuation mark is over. Then use the above shift-key combination.